# Redirecting xdg-open to another system?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, xdg

I frequently ssh into a linux system offsite and love to use tools like 'hub' and others that offer commandline tools that open X-apps (most commonly web-browsers).  However, it always fails because that system doesn't have the necessary capabilities (and even if it did, I wouldn't want to try and use Chrome through an exported X-display).

Is there a way to register something as an xdg-open URL handler that will intercept the url request and redirect it to my local end to be handled?

Comment: The handlers can be registered through `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (in case I forget to write a full answer later)

Comment: Right.. But any ideas on getting one to "redirect" Back to my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

https://github.com/suan/local-open

There is a script and comprehensive guide how to use it.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.